# angularjs unit test error with angular-cache module

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

```
   describe("unit test", function () {
        it('should have a GuestsAndRoomsController controller', function (){
            expect(guestsAndRoomsController).not.toBe(null);
        });
        it('should have default editPackageInclusions flag', function(){
            expect(guestsAndRoomsController).toEqual(null);

        });
    })
```

the module has dependency with `angular-cache`, and when I run this unit test, it pop up an error as follows:

> defaultCache already exists! in node_modules/angular-cache/dist/angular-cache.js

Comment: Somewhere you register defaultCache twice, but not in the code sample you provide..